# access_token not shown in .auth/me

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

When implementing React web application and authenticating using Azure App Service Authentication (easy auth) towards Azure B2C, what is the correct procedure to get access_token required to pass as Bearer token in subsequent calls to external (=separate web app from the React app) Azure web app API?

I can see the access_token being posted back to easy auth's `.auth/login/aad/callback`, but it isn't accessible on `.auth/me`, nor in Request Header "x-ms-token-aad-access-token".

Comment: Just set the client secret and you will get it

Comment: How would one do that? Idea of Azure App Service Authentication is to not have to worry about anything, nor even have access to any client ids or secrets.

Comment: Head to the App service > Authentication > AAD configuration > Avanced > Show secret
and put it there, the client secret is a client secret you get from app registration. The idea is that the token should be encrypted if you want to access it from the front end.

Comment: Don't have this scenario anymore, so cannot test it, but makes sense.